# Fill NA-values with Mean across column and row values

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have next dataframe

```
     A    B    C    D   E   F
0  158  158  158  177   1  10
1  158  158  158  177   2  20
2  177  177  177  177   3  30
3    1    3    5    7 NaN  10
4  177  177  177  177   6  50
```

Now I try to get a new one dataframe where **E3** = AVG[AVG(E)=3, AVG(3)=5]=4

```
     A    B    C    D   E   F
0  158  158  158  177   1  10
1  158  158  158  177   2  20
2  177  177  177  177   3  30
3    1    3    5    7  [4] 10
4  177  177  177  177   6  50
```

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match your problem description at all. Why have all the other row values in row 3 been modified? Why has the last row of E become 6? It looks as if you're really after interpolate

Comment: My bad, already fixed initial dataframe

Comment: Still wrong the average of (3 + 6)/2 = 4.5 not 4. Are you after `df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.interpolate())`

Comment: @EdChum OP want something like this, the math does not make sense, df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna( np.mean( [df.mean(axis=1),df.mean(axis=0)])))...This code does not work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a one-liner however if you can keep three data frames in memory

- one with row averages
- another with column averages
- third with the average of the above two

then `fillna` will replace `NaN` values based on the exact location in the third data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = [[158,158,158,177,1,10]
       ,[158,158,158,177,2,20]
       ,[177,177,177,177,3,30]
       ,[1,3,5,7,np.NaN,10]
       ,[177,177,177,177,6,50]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
# row and column means replicated over columns and rows
mean0 = (pd.concat([df.mean(axis=0)]*df.shape[0], axis=1, ignore_index=True)).transpose()
mean1 = pd.concat([df.mean(axis=1)]*df.shape[1], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
# average of mean0 and mean1
m = mean0.add(mean1)/2
df = df.fillna(m)
df
    0       1       2       3       4       5
0   158     158     158     177     1.0     10
1   158     158     158     177     2.0     20
2   177     177     177     177     3.0     30
3   1       3       5       7       4.1     10
4   177     177     177     177     6.0     50
```